# jQuery ajax request same page PHP doesnt execute

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a variable in a request to the same page and then check if the variable is set.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  {idss:idss},
            success: function(data){
                console.log("hello");
            }
        }); 

if(isset($_POST['idss'])){
    echo "Set";
}
```

However, when this runs I only see "hello" in the console and yet I dont see the output of 'echo' on the page.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything with `data` so you won't see what you echo in your PHP file. If you do `console.log(data)` you should see "set"

Comment: Yes.. on the PHP side, but not on the Javascript side so you won't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  {idss:idss},
            success: function(data){
                console.log("hello");
                $('#here').html(data['whatever_you_returned']);
            }
        }); 

   <div id="here"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I can now do what I need to

Answer (score 2):

The POST data is being sent to the page in your ajax request, not your current page. 
index.php would have that POST data set.

Comment: Ok then, how do I re-run the page so I can work with the data without reloading the page?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.... but, try putting console.log(data); inside your success function.  Your page is being run with the post data, but that would technically be done on a different request.  This request is being returned to your original page through the success function of your ajax call.  The 'Set' echo you're looking for should be there.